# How to delete one set of files in a directory containing similarly named files?

Tags: bash, shell

A series of several hundred directories contains files in the following pattern:

```
Dir1:
-text_76.txt  
-text_81.txt   
-sim_76.py   
-sim_81.py

Dir2:
-text_90.txt  
-text_01.txt   
-sim_90.py   
-sim_01.py
```

Within each directory, the files beginning with text or sim are essentially duplicates of the other text or sim file, respectively. Each set of duplicate files has a unique numerical identifier. I only want one set per directory. So, in Dir1, I would like to delete everything in the set labeled either 81 OR 76, with no preference. Likewise, in Dir2, I would like to delete either the set labeled 90 OR 01. Each directory contains exactly two sets, and there is no way to predict the random numerical IDs used in each directory. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you always have 1 known file, say `text_xx.txt` then you could run this script in each sub-directory:

```
ls text_*.txt | { read first; rm *"${first:4:4}"*; };
```

This will list all files matching the wildcard pattern `text_*.txt`.  Using `read` takes only the first matching result of the `ls` command.  This will result in a `$first` shell variable containing one fully expanded match: `text_xx.txt`.  After that `${first:4:4}` sub-strings this fully expanded match to get the characters `_xx.` by knowing the length of `test_` and `xx`.  Finally, `rm *""*` appends wild cards to the search result and executes it as a command: `rm *_xx.*`.

I chose to include `_` and `.` around `xx` to be a bit conservative about what gets deleted.

If the length of `xx` is not known, things gets a bit more complicated.  A safer command unsure of this length might be:

```
ls text_??.txt | { read first; rm *_"${first:5:2}".*; };
```

This should remove one "fileset" every time it is run in a given sub-directory.  If there is only 1 fileset, it would still remove the fileset.

**Edit:** Simplified to remove unnecessary use of IFS command.

**Edit:** Attempt to expand on and clarify the explanation.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the elements of the rm command construction a bit? Also, why does * expand to  "_xx." rather than "xx"? This solves my example handily, but I'm having a bit of trouble generalizing this solution for, say, differently structured filenames, where being able to match for just "xx" would be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | grep -P "*[81|76]*" | xargs -d"\n" rm
ls | grep -P "*[90|01]*" | xargs -d"\n" rm
```

How it works:

ls lists all files (one by line since the result is piped).

grep -P filter

xargs -d"\n" rm executes rm line once for every line that is piped to it.

Comment: There are several hundred directories, and I do not know the unique identifiers for the sets within them.

Comment: Hi, can you explain your answer a bit? Popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to. Thanks!

Comment: I actually got a different result from this. Full command as typed results in  "grep: nothing to repeat", "rm: missing operand".